# Get all records that have an associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

A `Post` has_many `Tags`. Each tag record has a name, like "fashion" or "business".

How can I get all posts that have the tag with name "fashion"?

```
# Get all posts
@posts = Post.all

# Get the filter tag
@filter_tag = Tag.find_by_name(params[:filter_name])
```

Ok so now we have all posts, and now I just want the @posts that have the @filter_tag. What should I do?

I could loop through each post, and check if it has the filter tag. If so, add it to an array. I'm sure Rails ActiveRecord has a better method though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your associations set up correctly then

```
@filter_tag_posts = @filter_tag.posts
```